# Save stream data inside database or csv file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have stream of data(stream of custom object). I am listening that stream data inside my bloc. I want to write that data inside csv file so I am listening that data inside my bloc. I am getting stream data inside my bloc. In real time it will huge data changing in milliseconds. I am planning to save this data inside database/csv file but those would be asynchronous operations. So is there any possibility that my write to db/csv operation is in progress & next stream value available to listen or i will loose some values inside stream.

In real time scenario data will be very large & changing in milliseconds. With small data issue is not happening.